# paginate through records with php and mssql server

Tags: php, sql-server, pagination

i just moved to asp and php and i'm able to connect to mssql database and retrieve records. what i'm currenlty finding it hard to do is how to do pagination through the records showing 10 records at a time.

```
<table width="40%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td>Item-</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Price</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
 while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      ?>
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $row['item'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['quantity'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['rprice'] ?></td>

  </tr>
  <?php
 }
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="left">Previous</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><div align="right">Next</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

PHP SCRIPT

```
<?php require_once('Connections/db.php'); ?>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item_table  order by item desc";
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql , $params, $options );
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );

if ($row_count === false)
   echo "Error in retrieveing row count.";
else
   echo $row_count;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OFFSET to get specific results:

```
$startingRow = 5;
$rowsPerPage = 10;

SELECT * FROM item_table  order by item desc 
OFFSET $startingRow ROWS FETCH NEXT $rowsPerPage ROWS ONLY
```

You will get results from 5th to 15th

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the paging in SQL Server, you can use the ROW_NUMBER function to order your rows & specify a starting point in the WHERE clause, and number of records in the TOP clause.

See the examples below. I prefer the CTE syntax.

```
--inline syntax
select top(10) * from (select row_number() over(order by item) as rid, * from item_table) as d where rid>10;

--cte syntax
with _numberedData as
(
    select 
        row_number() over(order by item) as rid,
        * 
    from item_table
)

select top(10)
    *
from _numberedData
where rid>10;
```